# Excel Macro Best Practice for Multiple options in If Statement or Case

Tags: excel, if-statement, lookup, vlookup, vba

I have multiple "Call Types" (from "Roaming" to "International") and I need a vlookup to apply the correct rate depending on the type in an excel macro.

What's the best practice to do this?

If CategoryType = "Roaming" AND Country coainted in List A
Then

If List B
Then

Do I use arrays? How do you check if a string is in an array in an IF statement?

---

Solved: I used Case and then included sub-cases to assign a new Category:

```
Select Case otype
Case "International"
    Select Case country
    Case "Australia", "China", "Singapore"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 68).Value = "R01"
    Case Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 68).Value = "R02"
    End Select
End Select
```

Comment: Using merged cells will make your/our job 10x more difficult.

Comment: I thought about that too, what do you think, should I remove the merged cells in A and just repeat it? (A2 and A3 both to "international")?

Comment: Yes - unmerge ColA entirely

Comment: Unmerged, updated the image. Also had the idea of providing each rate amount a rate type, I guess my idea is to use many many many nested if statements to assign each cell a rate category, then use a vlookup function to apply the correct rate???

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following formula (array formula, so use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to apply)

```
=MAX((B4:B7=B10)*(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(B11,C4:C7)),0,1))*D4:D7)
```

The one issue is that you may get a false result if the country you're searching for happens to be a substring of another country.  The only fix for that would be to put all your country names like `|France|Canada|UK|` and then add the pipes around the search country input.

[image]

Comment: Hey Tim, that looks great (never used MAX before), I tried using the small sample you provided, and it worked. Using it on the larger set, however, did not work.

Also, ideally looking for some Macro VBA code that would run.

Answer (score 0):

There could also be another option. When I handle such calculations, I try to avoid putting multiple values into a single field. Instead, I try to treat it like a database:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately there are too many countries within three categories that interchange to be able to list them all out, will try my luck and then post my terrible attempted calculation/macro :)